# SwiftUI - How to access UIHostingController from SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I have SwiftUI page, it's being navigated from UIKit view. I want to set a title to this page, what I'm doing is

```
// code of UIKit view
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
controller.title = "title"
MyNavigationManager.present(controller)
```

Is there a way I can access the hosting controller within SwiftUI?

Then I could write code like
 `self.hostingController?.title = "title"`

Comment: Finally I choose an easy way, in hosting controller, pass self into SwiftUI
rootView.hostingController = self

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - to use external configuration wrapper class to hold weak link to controller and inject it into SwiftUI view (as alternate it is also possible to make it `ObservableObject` to combine with other global properties and logic).

Tested with Xcode 12.5 / iOS 14.5

```
class Configuration {
    weak var hostingController: UIViewController?    // << wraps reference
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    let config: Configuration   // << reference here

    var body: some View {
        Button("Demo") {
            self.config.hostingController?.title = "New Title"
        }
    }
}

let configuration = ExtConfiguration()
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView(config: configuration))

// injects here, because `configuration` is a reference !!
configuration.hostingController = controller

controller.title = "title"
MyNavigationManager.present(controller)
```

Answer (score 7):

I went for a different option - subclass NSHostingController so that it provides itself as an environment variable.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var host:HSHostWrapper

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            host.controller?.dismiss(self)
        }
    }
}

let controller = HSHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
```

this is achieved with the following HSHostingController (which is available in the [HSSwiftUI package](https://github.com/ConfusedVorlon/HSSwiftUI))

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


#if os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
    import UIKit
    public typealias ViewController = UIViewController
    public typealias HostingController = UIHostingController
#elseif os(OSX)
    import AppKit
    public typealias ViewController = NSViewController
    public typealias HostingController = NSHostingController
#endif

public class HSHostWrapper:ObservableObject {
    public weak var controller:ViewController?
}


/// allows root view (and children) to access the hosting controller by adding
/// @EnvironmentObject var host:HSHostWrapper
/// then e.g. host.controller?.dismiss()
public class HSHostingController<Content>:HostingController<ModifiedContent<Content,SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<HSHostWrapper?>>> where Content : View {
    
    public init(rootView:Content) {
        let container = HSHostWrapper()
        let modified = rootView.environmentObject(container) as! ModifiedContent<Content, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<HSHostWrapper?>>
        super.init(rootView: modified)
        container.controller = self
    }
  
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

edit: Note - this approach is now deprecated in HSSwiftUI.
See my subsequent answer for a newer cleaner approach.

Answer (score 2):

I have a new solution.

This relies on an extension to ViewController that provides itself as the input to a ViewBuilder.

I think it is very clean

```
let controller = ViewController() {
    vc in
    vc.title = "title"
    return SwiftUIView()
}
MyNavigationManager.present(controller)
```

this relies on the HSSwiftUI package

https://swiftpackageindex.com/ConfusedVorlon/HSSwiftUI